# get process name of a binary without running it c++ cross platform

Tags: c++, file, user-interface, process

I want to get the process name of a binary both on windows and Linux without running it. I'm now implementing an interface for GUI communication and want to implement a file selection dialog(e.g user selects an executable file and the daemon/service deducts the process name). Is this doable?

Comment: _"I think the idea is clear."_ Unfortunately not (at least for me). What exactly do you mean with _process name_, isn't that the same as the executable's name??

Comment: no - you can't assume that. most of the time it's the same, sometimes it's not. the process name is the name it has when running - the binary can have a different name.

Comment: You mean when running the binary from a symbolic link or such?

Comment: By default, the OS chooses the executable name (more it doesn't know on process creation anyway). There're hacks to change on runtime, so the source of process memory isn't trackable but that's very rare. You better let your service start the process or expect process id input.

Comment: Sorry - I screwed up... I had my install.sh symlinking and actually forgot about it... Ignore my foolish question... I need to get some sleep it seems